# Using setState inside axios.fetch...then() with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a class component with react and this error popped up. Wondering, did anyone use a `this` inside `axios` before or know how to? Thank you in advance

```
type State = {
  fetchedPassword: string;
  fetchedPassword: string;
}

type Props = {

}

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props,State>() {

constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      fetchedPassword: "",
      fetchedUsername: ""
    }

}

  authLogin = (e:any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { fetchedUsername, fetchedPassword } = this.state;

    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        this.setState({ fetchedPassword: response.data.password }); //error appears here
        this.setState({ fetchedUsername: response.data.username }); //and here
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
      });
  }
}
```

The error says

```
'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
MyComponenet.tsx(26, 13): An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.
```

I'm not sure how to solve this

Comment: Just make it an arrow function `function (response) {` to `(response) => {`. Then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of you component instance **this** and store it in **that** constant:

```
authLogin = (e:any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { fetchedUsername, fetchedPassword } = this.state;

    const that = this

    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        that.setState({ fetchedPassword: response.data.password });
        that.setState({ fetchedUsername: response.data.username });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `authLogin` outside your `constructor`, then, as a last line in your constructor, add

```
this.authLogin = this.authLogin.bind(this);
```

See https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56/ for more info.